# Apple Music listening history

Tags: itunes, music, apple-music

Is there a way find a history of listened to music through Apple Music. The way I'm using it right now is:

1. Search for a given album/artist on the search bar on iTunes
2. The "New" tab is selected? (I can't understand why, most of the music I'm searching for were released decades ago)
3. I click on the big play button on the top - albums starts playing
4. I continue searching for more music, seeing related artists, etc

If I ever want to go back to the album view, I need to keep pressing the 'Back' button until the album appears. If I ever quit iTunes, I probably won't be able to find the album, unless I added it to my library.

I might just go back using last.fm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its available to me off the menu in the header.  click the menu icon, then click the clock icon in the pop-up.
[image: Previously Played Popup]

Answer (score 5):

Is there a bar on the bottom of the screen showing which song is currently playing?

[image: iOS 8.4 mini player]

If so you can try dragging that up and it should bring you to a screen that has more stuff on it.

[image: iOS 8.4 full player]

Click on the button that looks like three dots with horizontal lines to the right of them (it's to the right of the skip/fast forward button);

[image: Up Next button]

that will show "Up Next" if you scroll up you will see your History.

[image: Up Next scrolling up shows History]

Comment: To do the same on iTunes there is a clock icon on the numbered list button on the top bar. I fail so bad trying to figure what all those icons without alt texts do.